# Interaction between extended class and implemented interface

Tags: java, interface, java-8, default

```
public class Main {

public static class ClassBase {

    public void test() {
        System.out.println("1");
    }

}

public static interface Interface {

    default void test() {
        System.out.println("2");
    }

}

public static class MyClass extends ClassBase implements Interface {

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new MyClass().test();
}

}
```

In this example, it will always print 1.
To print 2, I must override `test` in `MyClass` and return `Interface.super.test()`.

Is there a way of making the `Interface::test` method override the `ClassBase::test` method without manually overriding the method in `MyClass` ?
(to print 2 in the example)

Comment: Is there a way? Sure, make the interface a class and the class an interface.

Comment: @shmosel The problem is that the class I'm using is from an API, and I can't change it. I wanted to create an interface to automatically override some methods from this class (that I'll reuse a lot of time, so it's less code needed), but it doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like you want your class only to implement interface. If thats the case let MyClass not extend ClassBase

Comment: Why don't you subclass `ClassBase` instead of trying to "inject" an unrelated interface?

Comment: @Anil But I need to access to ClassBase's other methods and fields. I must extend this class.

Comment: @shmosel I could. But I want my interface to work with all class that extends ClassBase, not only ClassBase itself.

Comment: So? Create a subclass and extend that in all of your classes.

Comment: @shmosel I think I found a solution. Thanks

Comment: Don't see the problem yet, but ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If any class in the hierarchy has a method with same signature, then default methods become irrelevant. A default method cannot override a method from java.lang.Object. The reasoning is very simple, it’s because Object is the base class for all the java classes. So even if we have Object class methods defined as default methods in interfaces, it will be useless because Object class method will always be used. That’s why to avoid confusion, we can’t have default methods that are overriding Object class methods.

**Conclusion:** Default method cannot override Instance method.

Comment: Well, thanks for the information, that's what I thought.

Comment: When you cite something, you should include a link to the source.